# Difference between AND and OR in WHERE condition of a SELECT statement in Mysql Database?

Tags: mysql

I have a database table called employee, When retrieving the name of the employee like this

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE Fname ='jack' AND Fname ='john';
```

This query returns an empty set. Tried Querying the database using the `OR` condition like this

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE Fname ='jack' OR Fname = 'John';
```

The query returns all the fields of jack and john from the employee table. My understanding of `AND` operator is `1 and 1 is true`, where Jack and John is in my table it should return the fields of jack and john from the employee table using the `AND` operator. Am I allowed to use `AND` condition on a single table, Have I misunderstood the concept. Please some good advice!

Comment: It would help if you post a sample of rows in your table together with a sample of what query output you are expecting to get. Boolean conditions in a `WHERE` clause like `AND` or `OR` are applied across multiple _columns_ in the _same row_, and so it is not possible for a row to have both values `Fname = 'jack' AND Fname = 'john'` because `Fname` can hold only one value per row.

Comment: Thank you Michael Berkowski and everybody who answered, I got the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition `Fname ='jack' AND Fname ='john'` means the query will match each row where `Fname` is both `'jack'` and `'john'`. Since a single column can't be two different values at once, this will match no rows.

Answer (score 2):

`WHERE Fname ='jack' AND Fname ='john'` returns an empty set because there is no record where Fname is both 'jack' AND 'john'. 'jack <> 'john'. If you want to return records when the Fname can be either `jack` or `john` then use `...WHERE Fname ='jack' OR Fname ='john'`.

Answer (score 2):

What you write in the `WHERE` clause is a **condition**. Writing `Fname = 'jack' AND Fname = 'john'` looks for people whose first name is "jack" and at the same time "john". But what you want is people whose first name is "jack" *or* "john".

Answer (score 1):

What you want is `or` because Fname can not be both jack and john

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE Fname ='jack' or Fname ='john';
```